# Codeception and Selenium doesn't show actions

Tags: selenium, laravel, laravel-4, codeception

I'm using laravel with codeception and selenium, I created a new `suite` called selenium and created this configuration file for it:

```
class_name: SeleniumTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - SeleniumHelper
        - WebDriver
        - Laravel4
    config:
        WebDriver:
            url: 'http://app.dev:8000/'
            browser: 'firefox'
            wait: 3
            capabilities:
                  unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept'
```

My test:

```
$I = new SeleniumTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Log in a visitor');
$I->am('Visitor');
$I->haveAnAccount();
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->fillField(LoginPage::$usernameField,LoginPage::$username);
$I->fillField(LoginPage::$passwordField,LoginPage::$password);
$I->click(self::$loginButton);
$I->seeInCurrentUrl('@uset');
```

Running `bin/codecept run selenium` it open firefox for about 1 sec with a **blank page** and it close automatically after then. The tests are running **correctly** on my console, but I cannot see the steps on firefox which will be really great if I may fix it.

What may be the problem? I'm using mac OS X 10.9.5

Answer (score 0):

What is that haveAnAccount() method? Maybe there is an error there and the script couldn't run through the next steps. Is it in the SeleniumHelper?

Try to start codeception in debug mode (to get more information) and comment the line haveAnAccount().

```
bin/codecept run -d selenium
```

HTH

Comment: The `haveAnAccount` method is just an helper for create an account, it is not the problem, but after hours of dig in I discovered that you cannot use `WebServer` and `Laravel4` Module at the same time. Now big problem is set the right environment when Acceptance tests are running. Laravel doesn't not run acceptance tests in `testing` env